# How can I add "warning message" to my program?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I write a program for my project with c++; however, I can not add "return warning message" in my algorithm.

My algrotihm;

```
#include<iostream>

#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

const int k=100;

class safearay{
    int arr[k];

    int getel(int index){ if(index>-1 && index<k) return arr[index];}};

void main(void)
{
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"<<endl;

    safearay safea1; int temp=23456;

    for{
    safea1.putel(7, temp);  temp=safea1.getel(7);
    cout<<temp;
    cout<<"\n\n !Press k to continue."<<endl<<endl;
    }while(getch()=='k');
}
```

How can i add warning messages' section?

Comment: You may use `throw` ?

Comment: how do I use throw? do you have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to return a flag stating that something went wrong from the `putel` function and printing the error in main.

```
bool putel(int index, int value){ 

    if(index <= -1 || index == 10 || index > LIMIT) {//the conditions that are invalid
       return false;
    }

     arr[index]=value;
     return true;
}
```

and in main something like this

```
 do{
     if(!safea1.putel(7, temp)){
        cout<<"Insert failed "<<endl; //Your warning message
     } else {
       temp=safea1.getel(7);
       cout<<temp;
       cout<<"\n\n !Press k to continue."<<endl<<endl;
   } while(getch()=='k');
```

I hope this was what you were looking for..

Answer (score 1):

You may use `throw`, something like:

```
class safearray
{
public:
    void putel(int index, int value) { check_index(index); arr[index] = value;}
    int getel(int index) const { check_index(index); return arr[index];}

private:
    void check_index(int index) const
    {
        if (index < 0 || LIMIT <= index) {
            throw std::out_of_range("bad index " + std::to_string(index) + " for safearray");
        }
    }
private:
    int arr[LIMIT];
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/rsUMKK)